# React: Saved state updates the DOM but not the console

Tags: reactjs

When I click, I set the `saveMouseDown` state to 1, when I release I set it to 0. 
When I click and move the mouse I log out `mouseDown` and it's 0 even when my mouse is down? Yet on the screen it shows 1

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Home: React.FC = () => {

  const [mouseDown, saveMouseDown] = useState(0);
  const [canvasWidth, saveCanvasWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [canvasHeight, saveCanvasHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  let canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;

  const addEventListeners = () => {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => { toggleMouseDown(); }, true);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => { toggleMouseUp(); }, true);
  };

  const toggleMouseDown = () => saveMouseDown(1);
  const toggleMouseUp = () => saveMouseDown(0);
  const printMouse = () => console.log(mouseDown);
//                               ^------ Why does this print the number 1 and the 2x 0 and then 1... and not just 1?

  const removeEventListeners = () => {
    canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', toggleMouseDown);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', toggleMouseUp);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      canvas = canvasRef.current;
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      addEventListeners();
    }
    return () => removeEventListeners();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      canvas = canvasRef.current;
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => { printMouse(); }, true );
    }
    return () => canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', printMouse);
  }, [mouseDown, printMouse]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Mouse Down: {mouseDown}</p>
{/*                      ^------ When this does print 1?     */}
    <canvas
      id='canvas'
      ref={canvasRef}
      width={canvasWidth}
      height={canvasHeight}
    />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export { Home };
```

Answer (score 1):

You only add the move listener once when the component mounted, thus enclosing the initial `mouseDown` value.

Try using a second `useEffect` hook to *specifically* set/update the onMouseMove event listener when the `mouseDown` state changes. The remove eventListener needs to specify the same callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (canvasRef.current) {
    canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', printMouse, true );
  }
  return () => canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', printMouse);;
}, [mouseDown, printMouse]);
```

It may be simpler to attach the event listeners directly on the `canvas` element, then you don't need to worry about working with enclosed stale state as much with the effect hooks.

```
<canvas
  onMouseDown={() => setMouseDown(1)}
  onMouseUp={() => setMouseDown(0)}
  onMouseMove={printMouse}
  width={canvasWidth}
  height={canvasHeight}
/>
```

[image: Edit compassionate-dubinsky-6cdov]

Comment: I gave this a shot and, this time when I click I get 0 and 1's even though I'm holding the mouse down?